Why isn't the table values showing even tho I have the correct routing for it?
So basically, I'm using flask and sqlite3 for my database. I tried every solution I can and I cannot seem to fix it
I made sure that the items_used table is passed on inside the database
@app.route('/generate_billing/<int:patient_id>', methods=['GET'])
def generate_billing(patient_id):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Fetch patient name
    cursor.execute('SELECT first_name, last_name FROM patients WHERE patient_id = ?', (patient_id,))
    patient = cursor.fetchone()
    if patient:
        patient_name = f"{patient['first_name']} {patient['last_name']}"
    else:
        patient_name = "Unknown"
        print(f"Patient with ID {patient_id} not found.")  # Debugging

    # Fetch diagnoses
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT tooth_number, condition_code, cost, date_of_diagnosis
        FROM conditions
        WHERE patient_id = ?
    ''', (patient_id,))
    diagnoses = cursor.fetchall()
    print(f"Diagnoses: {diagnoses}")  # Debugging

    # Fetch items used
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT i.item_name, iu.quantity, iu.date_of_diagnosis, i.cost
        FROM items_used iu
        JOIN Items i ON iu.item_id = i.item_id
        WHERE iu.patient_id = ?
    ''', (patient_id,))
    items_used = cursor.fetchall()
    print(f"Items Used Query: SELECT i.item_name, iu.quantity, iu.date_of_diagnosis, i.cost FROM items_used iu JOIN Items i ON iu.item_id = i.item_id WHERE iu.patient_id = {patient_id}")
    print(f"Items Used: {items_used}")  # Debugging

    # Calculate total cost
    total_cost = sum(d['cost'] for d in diagnoses if d['cost']) + sum(item['quantity'] * item['cost'] for item in items_used if item['cost'])
    print(f"Total Cost: {total_cost}")  # Debugging

    conn.close()

    # Get current date
    current_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    return render_template('billing.html', patient_name=patient_name, patient_id=patient_id, diagnoses=diagnoses, items_used=items_used, total_cost=total_cost, current_date=current_date)

I have an Items Used table wherein there are only 2 columns which are Item and Quantity which should show the values of the columns item_name inside the Item table as well as quantity inside the items_used table
As a reference here's the structure for the items_used table
CREATE TABLE "items_used" (
    "iu_id" INTEGER,
    "patient_id"    INTEGER,
    "quantity"  INTEGER,
    "item_id"   INTEGER,
    "date_of_diagnosis" DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY("patient_id") REFERENCES "patients"("patient_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("item_id") REFERENCES "Items"("item_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("iu_id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

and here's a reference for the Items table
CREATE TABLE "Items" (
    "item_id"   INTEGER,
    "item_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "item_description"  TEXT,
    "supplier_id"   INTEGER,
    "unit"  TEXT,
    "cost"  REAL DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY("supplier_id") REFERENCES "Suppliers"("supplier_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("item_id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

Here's my flask template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Billing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    <style>
        .billing-container {
            background-color: #5D2E26;
            color: #f3edea;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .billing-container h2, .billing-container h3 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .billing-container table {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .billing-container table th, .billing-container table td {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .billing-container table th {
            background-color: #7f4a37;
        }

        .billing-container table td {
            background-color: #a96b58;
        }

        .billing-container button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            background-color: #8B4513;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .billing-container button:hover {
            background-color: #D2691E;
        }

        .costbox {
            width: 60px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar-tab" id="sidebarTab">☰</div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('users') }}">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('treatments') }}">Treatment</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">Records</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('patients') }}">Patient Records</a>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('appointment_records') }}">Appointment Records</a>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('treatment_records') }}">Treatment Records</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('maintenance') }}">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('inventory') }}">Inventory</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('reports') }}">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('payments') }}">Payments</a></li>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('help') }}">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="billing-container">
        <h2>Billing for {{ patient_name }}</h2>

        <h3>Conditions and Treatments</h3>
        <form action="{{ url_for('update_billing', patient_id=patient_id) }}" method="post">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tooth Number</th>
                        <th>Condition</th>
                        <th>Cost (₱)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for diagnosis in diagnoses %}
                        {% if diagnosis['date_of_diagnosis'] == current_date %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ diagnosis['tooth_number'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ diagnosis['condition_code'] }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" name="diagnosis_cost_{{ diagnosis['tooth_number'] }}_{{ diagnosis['condition_code'] }}" value="{{ diagnosis['cost'] }}" step="0.01" min="0" required class="costbox">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <h3>Items Used</h3>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for item in items_used %}
                        {% if item['date_of_diagnosis'] == current_date %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ item['item_name'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item['quantity'] }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <h3>Total Cost: ₱{{ total_cost }}</h3>

            <button type="submit">Update Costs</button>
        </form>

        <button id="printBillButton">Print Bill</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const printBillButton = document.getElementById('printBillButton');
            printBillButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                window.print();
            });

            const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
            const sidebarTab = document.getElementById('sidebarTab');
            const mainContent = document.querySelector('.billing-container');

            sidebarTab.addEventListener('click', function () {
                sidebar.classList.toggle('show');
                mainContent.classList.toggle('shifted');
                sidebarTab.style.display = 'none';
            });

            document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                if (!sidebar.contains(event.target) && !sidebarTab.contains(event.target)) {
                    sidebar.classList.remove('show');
                    mainContent.classList.remove('shifted');
                    sidebarTab.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });

            const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
            dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
                const btn = dropdown.querySelector('.ellipsis-btn');
                const content = dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

                btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    content.classList.toggle('show');
                });

                document.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    content.classList.remove('show');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Does print(f"Items Used: {items_used}") show the expected result?

Are you using dictionary cursors?

It doesn't show the expected result when I ran print(f"Items Used: {items_used}")

Well, what does it show?  Don't make us guess.

oh sorry bout that, It just showed Items Used: []

Okay, so that query really did not find anything, which explains why the table is blank.  So now the next question is, why didn't the query find anything?  Are you able to run that same query in a database browser?

I have data in the table, here's a picture for reference
https://imgur.com/a/mb9TlhQ

@PLAWD Please post sample data as text. We can't copy/paste images into a test database.

That's not the same query from the code.  To test this, you need to run the exact same query as the code uses.

So, I ran the exact query in a database browser and it didn't display anything

Execution finished without errors.
Result: 0 rows returned in 7ms
At line 1:
SELECT i.item_name, iu.quantity, iu.date_of_diagnosis, i.cost
FROM items_used iu
JOIN Items i ON iu.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE iu.patient_id = ?

Then that means that either the patient ID doesn't exist in the items_used table, or there are no corresponding item_id values in the items table.

Since the query returned results when you just searched items_used, this points the finger at the items table. Do you have foreign key support enabled in your SQLite implementation? That should prevent this.

I have it enabled, however I have no clue what to do next

Okay, so it seems the real problem is "this query doesn't produce the results I expected", which is quite different from the question you posted...

Actually I fixed it just now, it did have a problem with the items table since I accidentally removed the cost column. Thank you!

If the cost column didn't exist, then I don't see how that query ran at all.  But hey, it's working, so all's well that ends well.
